# My TLS-Client isnt working when trying to scrape Prizepicks API

Tags: python

import tls_client
import pandas as pd

def dfs_scraper():
headers = {
'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,'
'application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'cache-control': 'no-cache',
'pragma': 'no-cache',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="91", "Google Chrome";v="91"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

```
requests_session = tls_client.Session(client_identifier="chrome112")

# Fetch data from Prizepicks API
response = requests_session.get('https://api.prizepicks.com/projections', headers=headers)
prizepicks = response.json()

# Initialize List and Dictionaries to Store Data
pplist = []
library = {}

for included in prizepicks['included']:
    if 'attributes' in included and 'name' in included['attributes']:
        PPname_id = included['id']
        PPname = included['attributes']['name']
        if 'team' in included['attributes']:
            ppteam = included['attributes']['team']
        else:
            ppteam = 'N/A'
        if 'league' in included['attributes']:
            ppleague = included['attributes']['league']
        else:
            ppleague = 'N/A'
        library[PPname_id] = {'name': PPname, 'team': ppteam, 'league': ppleague}

for ppdata in prizepicks['data']:
    PPid = ppdata.get('relationships', {}).get('new_player', {}).get('data', {}).get('id', 'N/A')
    PPprop_value = ppdata.get('attributes', {}).get('line_score', 'N/A')
    PPprop_type = ppdata.get('attributes', {}).get('stat_type', 'N/A')
    versus_team = ppdata.get('attributes', {}).get('description', 'N/A')

    ppinfo = {"name_id": PPid, "Stat": PPprop_type, "Prizepicks": PPprop_value, "Versus": versus_team}
    pplist.append(ppinfo)

for element in pplist:
    name_id = element['name_id']
    if name_id in library:
        player_data = library[name_id]
        element['Name'] = player_data['name']
        element['Team'] = player_data['team']
        element['League'] = player_data['league']
    else:
        element['Name'] = "Unknown"
        element['Team'] = "N/A"
        element['League'] = "N/A"
    del element['name_id']

rows = []
for element in pplist:
    name = element['Name']
    league = element['League']
    team = element['Team']
    stat = element['Stat']
    versus_team = element['Versus']

    prizepicks_value = element['Prizepicks']
    if league == 'LoL' and '+' not in name:
        rows.append((name, league, team, stat, versus_team, prizepicks_value))

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Name', 'League', 'Team', 'Stat', 'Versus', 'Prizepicks'])
print(df)
return df
```

dfs_scraper()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ctypes/**init**.py", line 460, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ctypes/**init**.py", line 379, in **init**
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tls_client/dependencies/tls-client-x86.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tls_client/dependencies/tls-client-x86.dylib: cannot load 'tls-client-x86.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tls_client/dependencies/tls-client-x86.dylib: cannot load 'tls-client-x86.dylib' (load command 0x80000034 is unknown)